# How to add Entity Attributes dynamically to a Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to add Entity Attributes to a Grid Dynamically, but getting the error as below. Can anyone please suggest me how I can populate grid dynamically. Thanks

```
@Html.Grid(Model.SearchResults).Columns(columns =>
{                                   
     columns.Add(c => c.Id).Titled("Id");

     foreach (var attribute in Model.SearchResults[0].Attributes)
     {                            
         columns.Add(c => c.Attributes[attribute.Key]).Filterable(true);
     }                        
}).WithPaging(100).Sortable(true)
```

**Error**

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   GridMvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Expression 'c =>
>   c.Attributes.get_Item(value(ASP._Page_Views_Queries_ResultGrid_cshtml+<>c__DisplayClass1).attribute.Key)'
>   not supported by grid

Answer (score 0):

Columns.Add().RenderValueAs(c => c.Attributes[attribute.Key]).Titled("Employee").Filterable(true)